# I need to rollup columns data into a single row

Tags: sql-server

I had a need to transpose a given column into multiple added columns using a view, placing the value of a second column into the appropriate added column, then having only one value across all the added columns for a given record.  Column A and B are the columns to group by.  Added columns C - F now have one text value per record (number as a varchar).  I now want to group the records to one record, now where every added column holds one value for the grouping. Perhaps a complication is that one or more of the added columns may have all NULL values for a given grouping.  I know how to do this if numberic values, then summing and grouping, but these are numbers as varchar.  I have not been able to apply any of the 'Similar questions'

```
CREATE TABLE Transposed(
    enterdate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Area VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ColC VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ColD VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ColE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ColF VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO Transposed
VALUES
 ('1/1/2021', 'A', '25', '', '', '')
,('1/1/2021', 'A', '', '35', '', '')
,('1/1/2021', 'A', '', '', '', '')
,('1/1/2021', 'A', '', '', '', '45')

Select * From Transposed
```

Where the result can be reduced to one line:

```
1/1/2021,   A,      25,      35,        Null,      45
```

Answer (score 2):

one way :

```
select Area 
    ,enterdate 
    , max(ColC) as ColC
    , max(ColD) as ColD
    , ...
from Transposed
group by Area,enterdate
```

Comment: Perfect... Thank you eshirvana. Now to code this for the 48 added columns.